# Req.files.file.length undefined when one file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm working on a multiple files upload using Reactjs/Node.js/Expressjs.

I can upload multiple files to my uploads directory in my backend and to my database.

But when I try to upload only one file nothing happens.

On the Front the file is correctly selected and when I `console.log(this.state.selectedFile.length)` I got 1, it works.

But on the backend when I use `console.log(myFile.length)` I got undefined. If I upload 2 or more files the console.log shows the correct length and I don't know why.

**My code (backend)**

```
export const uploadFile = (req, res) => {
  const myFile = req.files.file;
  // upload file(s) to directory
  for (let i = 0; i < myFile.length; i++) {
    myFile[i].mv("./src/uploads/" + myFile[i].name, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
    // save file(s) to database
    Upload.create({
      type: myFile[i].mimetype,
      name: myFile[i].name,
      data: myFile[i].data
    });
  }
  console.log(myFile.length);
  res.send("files uploaded !");
};
```

If you want more code/explanations feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const myFile = (Array.isArray(req.files.file)?req.files.file:[req.files.file]).filter(e=>e);
    // filter is important, so that you have [] instead of [undefined] if req.files.file is undefined
```

Might do the trick because one file might be an object and more an array. so the trick is to reconsider non array for array

Comment: It works ! Thanks. Can you explain why my method doesn't work ?

Comment: you received only an object when receiving only one file(had the problem with parsers), this trick is to redefine this object as an array of 1 item, i added a filter in case of undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you have only 1 element the "req.files.file" is not an array ?

Comment: Ok I didn't know that